# Help with tuning parameters in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, performance

I need a help with tuning parameters in my.cnf for efficient work of my web-site. I've been reading different articles, forum entries etc. regarding this topic, however I still keep getting problems.

Depending on the value of max_user_connection I either get an error saying that it's too low(if it's less than 300), or my server goes down after mysql taking all the server resources(if max_user_connections if over 300).

Can someone give me advices regarding tuning my.cnf options?

On my server, I have a 1 Wordpress blog with multi-site option enabled. This is a news web-site with a very large traffic. I have 6 GB of RAM on the server.
Here's my current settings:

```
skip-locking
safe-show-database

myisam_sort_buffer_size=96M
interactive_timeout=50
wait_timeout=10
connect_timeout=10
max_user_connections=150
max_connections=400

max_heap_table_size = 32M
max_connect_errors=10
key_buffer=256M
join_buffer=2M
record_buffer=2M
sort_buffer=64M
max_allowed_packet=24M

query_cache_limit = 128M
query_cache_size = 512M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 65K
query_alloc_block_size = 128K
read_buffer_size=1M
read_rnd_buffer_size=768K

log_slow_queries = /tmp/slow.log

tmp_table_size=128M
table_cache=4096
thread_cache=1024
thread_concurrency=8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic answer to improving your MySQL server performance. You need to make a change, then restart your MySQL server and *benchmark*.

Make sure your thread concurrency is set to 2x the number of cores in the server's CPU.

You may want to try increasing your query cache size also, if its too small then you may have a lot of cache fragmentation (which degrades performance).

Comment: There is no point to have thread_concurrency in any mysql setup anymore. From oracle mysql blog :

"....Thread_concurrency is a setting for only Solaris that has no effect in recent Solaris versions like 11. For Solaris 8 and earlier it gave the thread system a hint about how many threads to use for MySQL. Solaris 8 was last a supported platform for MySQL 5.1. We have deprecated this setting from 5.6.1 and removed it from 5.7....."

https://blogs.oracle.com/supportingmysql/entry/remove_on_sight_thread_concurrency

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqltuner.pl`. It suggests, what parameter you can moidify (with what value). 
It is really a perfect utillity for modfying `my.cnf` parameters.

Usage:

`wget mysqltuner.pl`

and run this script.

Also You can try with defragment the tables. If your server is physical and dedicated to only MySQL [few instances] then you might again try to increase few parameter and check the performance.
Use Benchmark each time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason to limit the number of connections, you can try setting max_user_connections to zero (which means no limit).